# in kernel program get root user id and compare with current user id

Tags: c, linux, kernel, root

As we know, the root uid is 0. so I tried to compare current process uid with 0. as follows:

```
uid_eq(get_current_cred()->uid, 0)
```

however, I get *incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘uid_eq’*

I have also tried

```
uid_eq(get_current_cred()->uid, (kuid_t)0)
```

but this also give this *error: conversion to non-scalar type requested*

How should I check if the current process is root in kernel? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kuid_t` is a struct, so you should declare one, and set it's `val` member to `0`.

Try this

```
kuid_t rootUid;

rootUid.val = 0;
uid_eq(get_current_cred()->uid, rootUid);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have not realized kuid_t is struct type. Your answer is right, but just for checking get_current_cred()->uid.val == 0 is enough.

Comment: May be, but the struct could change in the future, I think that's why there is a `uid_eq` function, so in principle, you could do it with `memset(&rootUid, 0, sizeof(rootUid));` and use the `uid_eq` function, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you! Also, in case the user has run the program with sudo, should I have checked with `uid_eq(get_current_cred()->euid, rootUid);`?

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't know how `sudo` works, and I actually never use `sudo`, you should try that by printing `get_current_cred()->euid.val` value, I would try it.